# apt-get Failing for all packages

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I'm running ubuntu 14.04, and I've recently started having issues with apt-get.  I can't install or remove any package (error below).  I tried reinstalling these packages, I tried deleting the deb files and I still get the same error.

```
    The following extra packages will be installed:
    python3-software-properties software-properties-common
    software-properties-gtk
    The following packages will be upgraded:
    python3-software-properties software-properties-common
    software-properties-gtk
    3 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 412 not upgraded.
    108 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/126 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
    dh-python software-properties-common software-properties-gtk
    python3-software-properties
    Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
    (Reading database ... 305261 files and directories currently         installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-common_0.92.37.7_all.deb ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.prerm: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
    dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-common_0.92.37.7_all.deb (--unpack):
    subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-common.postinst: py3compile: not found
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
    Preparing to unpack .../software-properties-gtk_0.92.37.7_all.deb ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.prerm: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
    dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-gtk_0.92.37.7_all.deb (--unpack):
    subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/software-properties-gtk.postinst: py3compile: not found
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
    Preparing to unpack .../python3-software-properties_0.92.37.7_all.deb ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.prerm: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
    dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
    /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: py3clean: not found
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-software-properties_0.92.37.7_all.deb (--unpack):
    subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
    /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-software-properties.postinst: py3compile: not found
    dpkg: error while cleaning up:
    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
    Errors were encountered while processing:
    /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-common_0.92.37.7_all.deb
    /var/cache/apt/archives/software-properties-gtk_0.92.37.7_all.deb
    /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-software-properties_0.92.37.7_all.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I'd start debugging with "The following packages cannot be authenticated!". You shouldn't get that. Do you get that with all packages, or just some? Can you post the output of `apt-cache policy` into your question, please?

Comment: Add to question what you typed to get error.

Comment: Not enough info in question to know for sure, but do an `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade`, then try again.

Comment: @FaheemMitha When ever I get "The following packages cannot be authenticated!", in debian, an `apt-get update`, fixes it.

Comment: Hi @richard. Sure, I'm assuming the poster knows enough to run an `apt-get update`, but I'm thinking it might be the sign of third-party packages. In any case, Alan, please do run `apt-get update` and see if it makes those messages go away.

Comment: Thanks all, I have done apt-get update and that runs fine.  @farheem - I went to run apt-cache policy and in an unfortunate turn of events, I can no longer log in... I sign in, the screen goes blank and then it makes a weird bing noise and lands me back at the login page.  Tried this post - https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop, but since apt-get is broken I can't try most of the solutions...  I will likely be posting a new thread and then returning to the apt-get issue when I can get that solved

Comment: @faheem - It's become clear I can't solve the login issue without apt-get, so I was able to get apt-cache policy to file, and sftp'ed that out to another machine, but I can't add it to the question because it contains more than 2 links (which you need 10 reputation points for), and it's too long for comments by 8k chars, is there a good way to get that onto here?

Comment: Hi @AlanP: you could put it in a pastebin, link the pastebin, and ask for someone to add it to the question.

Comment: Great News - I figured out the problem (that I'm a moron), I deleted Python 3.4 and replaced it with 3.5.  Based on a couple other posts like this , https://askubuntu.com/questions/814577/cant-install-or-remove-anything-on-ubuntu-16-04-because-py3clean-and-py3compile, it's pretty clear that caused my problems and I'm reinstalling Linux.  Thanks for the help here

Answer (score 0):

> py3compile: not found

The `py3compile` command is part of `python3-minimal` package which seems to be broken.

To fix the issue, try the following:

- Correct a system with broken dependencies in place by:

  ```
  sudo apt-get  -f install
  ```
- Reconfigure all unpacked, but unconfigured packages by:

  ```
  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  ```
- If above won't help, try reinstalling `python3-minimal` package by:

  ```
  sudo apt install -f --reinstall python3-minimal
  ```

  Alternatively run:

  ```
  apt-get download python3-minimal
  sudo dpkg -i *python3*.deb
  sudo apt install -f
  ```

  Or download the [`.pkg` file from kernel.org](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3-defaults/) and install from the file by:

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i python3-minimal_*.deb
  ```

Then make sure that `py3compile` and `py3clean` commands are runnable and are accessible from your `PATH` variable.